# How to use custom pagination in laravel 5.2 using LengthAwarePaginator

Tags: laravel-5, pagination

How to use custom pagination in laravel 5.2 using Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator , i think this gives more flexibility than other class according to thier doc. But couldn't figure it out how to do that . So i need help on this . Kindly guide me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Code in controller :

public function index(Request $request )
    {
            $data=array();

```
        //**** fetch data starts

        $countries_db = DB::table('location_country as lc');
        $countries_db=$countries_db->select(DB::raw('lc.id,lc.country_name,lc.country_3_code,lc.country_2_code,lc.lat,lc.lng,lc.published'));



        $pagi_country=$countries_db;


        //**** fetch data ends

        //***** pagination code starts

       $pagi_country = $pagi_country->paginate(3);

       $pagi_country->setPath('country/');



        $data['pagi_country']=$pagi_country;
        $data['useinPagiAr']=$useinPagiAr;
        //***** pagination code ends


      return view('admin.country.countrylist', $data);
}
```

### Code in View

we will get data from this variable $pagi_country  passing it to foreach loop , and printing data. To print the pagination link following  code is needed
echo $pagi_country->appends($useinPagiAr)->render();

Comment: In Controller what do you refer as `useinPagiAr`..I'm having the same concept here.I hope so that your's might help.Can you clarify it!!

Comment: Its just a custom defined array variable  where i pass search and sorting related data